# How can we retrieve table name of a hive view from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, metadata

There is a hive table employee.
On this employee table, there is view employee_view

How can we retrieve table-name (employee) for a given hive view (employee_view) from spark ?

Comment: What if you get the DDL of the view?

Comment: @Lamanus : not sure about api and syntax. Kindly share an example for fetching table name for the hive view.

Comment: Using this you will get view creation DDL ,`spark.sql("show create table <viewname>")` .Then you can split that string using from as a keyword and you will get a table name.

Comment: you can also use `describe formatted <view_name>`, which will work even if you have no privilege to execute `show create`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Make sure you have enabled hive support in spark session.

```
    val tableName = spark.sql("show create table employee_view").collect.mkString.split("from")(1).replace("]","")
    println(tableName)
```